# how can build single board computer like Raspberry Pi for run OS?

Tags: embedded, arm, embedded-linux, microprocessors

my question is : how can build single board computer like Raspberry Pi for run OS ?

user ARM micro processor and debian arm os , can use USB and etc.

like raspberry pi and other single board computer

i search but find nothing for help me !!! :(

Comment: select a processor and other peripheral chips, design a circuit board, pay a fabrication/assembly house, profit!

Comment: typically you want to start with a reference design like the raspberry pi.  beagleboard, beaglebone, pandaboard, open-rd, raspberry pi, etc any one of these and many many more can serve as the reference design then change the design based on what you need, and use the reference design's linux and modify as needed.

Comment: The raspberry pi uses a package on package arrangement so not only is it bga but it is bga on top of bga.  If you dont know how to do this stuff, do not start there.  Find a part that is a flat pack, with pins sticking out that you can solder yourself (with practice) on a board.   if the desired activity is bringing up an operating system and not bringing up a board either use an existing board or use an instruction set simulator like qemu.

Comment: if you want to build your own whatever around a single board computer, basically customize a system, then you can start with existing single board computer modules like micromint.com or embeddedarm.com or many others.

Comment: @dwelch:  You have a lot of useful advice - why not post an answer rather than comments?  Mine was written to show the scope and size of the problem and is likely to be off-putting.  Some more encouraging balance would probably be useful.

Comment: had intended to only be one comment, then added to it the more I thought about it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you can find nothing is probably because it is a specialist task undertaken by companies with appropriate resources in terms of expertise, equipment, tools and money.

High-end microprocessors capable of running an OS such as Linux use high-pin-density surface mount packages such as BGA or TQFP, these (especially BGA) require specialist equipment to manufacture and cannot reliably or realistically be assembled by hand.  The pin count and density necessitates the use of multi-layer boards, these again require specialist manufacture.

What you would have to do if you wanted your own board, is to design your board, source the components, and then have it manufactured by a contract electronics assembly house.  Short runs and one-off's will cost you may times that of just buying a COTS development or application board. It is only cost-effective if you are ultimately manufacturing a product that will sell in high volumes.  It is only these volumes that make the RPi so inexpensive (and until recently Chinese manufacture).

Even if you designed and had your own board built, that in itself requires specialist knowledge and skill.  The bus speeds on such processors require very specific layout to maintain signal integrity and timing and to avoid EMC problems.  The cost of suitable schematic capture and board layout software might also be prohibitive, no doubt there are some reasonably capable open source tools - but you will have to find one that generates output your manufacturer can use to set-up their machinery.

Some lower-end 8 bit microcontrollers with low pin count are suitable for hand soldering or even DIP socketing, using a bread-board or prototyping board, but that is not what you are after.

---

**[Further thoughts added 14 Sep 2012]**

This is probably only worth doing if one or more of the following are true:

- Your aim is to gain experience in board design, manufacture and bring-up as an academic or career development exercise and you have the necessary financial resources.
- You envisage high production volumes where the economies of scale make it less expensive than a COTS board.
- You have product requirements for specific features or form-factor not supported by COTS boards.
- You have restricted product requirements where a custom board tailored to those and having no redundant features might, in sufficient volumes be cost-effective.

Note that COTS boards come in two types:  Application modules intended for integration in a larger system or product, and development boards that tend to have a wide range of peripherals, switches, indicators and connectivity options and often a prototyping area for your own use.

Comment: Yup - just learning the CAD package to design a multi-layer board takes a lot of time, and then the gerbers bounce back several times because insufficient clearances, overlapping vias etc.  When you get a board back and have it built, it will not work because the power-supply chips are wired backwards, the RS232 connector is a DTE instead of DCE etc, etc.  When that's fixed, it board will be unreliable because you haven't put in enough capacitors round the CPU.  This merry-go-round can go on for ages...

Comment: Now come on, everyone has to start somewhere, sure if you think you are going to save a few bucks (hard to save a few bucks when the raspi is out there for $25) by making your own, that is always a failure.  But if you want to learn how to do this stuff, you have to start somewhere and there are flat pack boards and free tools and inexpensive board houses where you can learn, not at 600 mhz sure, but slower for starters.

Comment: @dwelch: Of course there are, but the OP wants something that will run Linux, which is not a great experience below 200Hz, a few hundred MB of RAM and an MMU equipped processor. You do indeed have to start somewhere, but if you have to ask the question, you are probably starting too high if you are doing this without commercial support from an employer.  While software tools may be available, debugging such hardware is likely to require high-end test equipment too - JTAG, DSO, Logic Analyser etc.  You could be wasting a lot of time and money starting out too ambitious and too ill-equipped.

Comment: jtag is no longer expensive, under $50.

Comment: I fully understand your point, having experienced folks work with you and show you is definitely a bonus.  Not necessarily required depending on where you live, they have these places like gyms where you pay a membership, but instead you get access to scopes and soldering stations, etc.  And I agree if the OP doesnt know anything about what we are talking about the likelyhood of success is low, at least on the first X number of tries, but you learn with each try, maybe you realize you didnt need linux.

Comment: I didnt see the OP say linux, a $5 microcontroller and a $10 pcb and a soldering iron $15 for a usb to serial plus power thing and you have a platform for writing an operating system, not linux but something.  Not raspberry pi either, sure.  From all the posts assuming the OP can read our english, should provide enough hesitation to think about this.  It is almost guaranteed you wont hit a home run the first time at bat, and almost guaranteed that you wont save money making your own vs just buying one that is out there, been there done that.

Comment: @dwelch: re. JTAG - sure, but there is a wide range of performance and features between a $50 wiggler and high-end equipment.

Comment: My high end jtag unit sits in a box collecting dust, I prefer the $27 for daily use.  significantly better software with the wigglers than the high end closed source, bill you for every little thing, products.  Tired of forking out $1000 bucks every time the wind changes direction.  for example I pay one time to get the ft2232 based device and can use it on any target I want.

Comment: @dwelch:  Good enough is of course good enough.  And you are of course right; I currently use Keil ULINK2 which is only usable with Keil uVision and Windows, and all of our old original ULINKs no longer work with Windows 7 or Cortex-M.  We have one ULINKPro where the instruction-level trace capability is often useful, and is much faster.  Previously I have used Abatron BDI2000 which can program a wide range of external Flash devices and uses an Ethernet interface, so there are no driver issues.  All useful stuff, but at considerable cost.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I've been looking into the same thing, possibly for different reasons, and it now comes up at the top of a google search providing more reasons not to ask or even look into it than it provides answers.

For an overview of what it takes to build a linux running board from scratch this link is incredibly useful:

http://hforsten.com/making-embedded-linux-computer.html

It details:

- The bare minimum you need in terms of hardware ( ARM processor, NAND flash etc )
- The complexities of getting a board designed
- The process of programming the new chip on the board to include bootloaders and then pointing them to a linux kernel for the chip to boot.

Whether the OP wishes to pursue every or just some of these challenges, it is useful to know what the challenges are.

And these won't be all of them, adding displays, graphics and other hardware and interfaces is not covered, but this is a start.

Answer (score 1):

Single board computers(SBC) are expected to take more load than normal hobby board and so it has slightly complicated structure in terms of PCB and components. You should be ready to work with BGA packages. Almost all of processors in SBCs are BGA (no DIP/QAFP). [Here](http://hforsten.com/making-embedded-linux-computer.html) is the best blogpost that I recently came across. Its very nicely designed and fabricated board running Linux on ARM processor. Author has really done a great job at designing as well as documenting the process. I hope it helps you to understand both hardware and software side of SBCs.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of answers are discouraging. **But, I would say you can do it, as I have done it already with imx233**. Its not easy, its not a weekend project. My project link is [MyIMX233](https://github.com/samarjit/MyIMX233).

- It took me about 4-5months
- It didn't cost me much, a small fine tip soldering iron is what I used.
- The hard part is learning to design PCB.
- Next task would be to find a PCB manufacturer with good enough precision, and prototyping price.
- Next task would be to source components.
- You may not get it right, I got the PCB right by my 3rd iteration. After that I was able to repeatedly produce 3 more boards all of which worked fine.

PCB Design - I used opensource KiCAD. You need to take care in doing impedance matching between RAM and processor buses, and some other high speed buses. I managed to do it in 2 layer board with 5mil/5mil trace space.

Component Sourcing - I got imx233 LQFP once via mouser, and once via element14.
RAM - 64MB tssop.

Soldering - I can say its easy to mess up here, but key is patience. And one caution don't use frying pan and solder past to do reflow soldering. I literally fried my first 2 processors like this. Even hot air soldering by a mobile repair shop was also not good enough.

Boot loading image - I didn't take much chance here, just went with Archlinux image by olimex.

If you want to skip the trouble of circuit designing between RAM & processor, skip imx233 and go for Allwinner V3S. In 2017/2018 this would be easiest approach.

*Bottom line is I am a software engineer by profession, and if I can do it, then you can do it.*

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an FPGA board?
Something with Zynq like the [Zybo board](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/1-4azfte.html) or from Altera like the [DE0-Nano SoCKit](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=167&No=941).

There you already have the ARM core, memory, etc... plus the possibility to add the logic you miss.

Comment: The question was about developing an own board, not to buy one

Comment: Buying an FPGA board is a step in between.
if the op really wants to develop his own board than there is a lot to study. 

I mean... I do it as a job, and for a single system we work in more than 10 people. Making a raspberry pi alike board is absolutely not trivial, especially without at least a bachelor in electrical engineering